# https webpage works on every system / browser / connection except on my Android with mobile data

Tags: android, apache, ssl, mobile, ssl-certificate

Sorry for posting this weird problem here, but I couldn't find a suitable section or other great page because I absolutely don't know where the problem really is. I've managed to fix several errors in the past without help, but in this case I simple don't know where the problem is located and where to look.

- I have a SSL-secured webpage (https://sager.io), all online tests I ran regarding SSL configuration say everything is fine
- I can access it via desktop, Windows and Linux, Chrome and Firefox
- My colleagues can access it over a variety of phone models like Samsung, IPhone or OnePlus via mobile data and wifi
- I can access the page with my phone (Xiaomi Mi9) via wifi **but not via mobile data**
  The site tries to load a few seconds, then the following errors appear:

  > "Connection closed unexpectedly" (Chrome) / "Secure connection failed" (Firefox)
- I have placed my SIM card in my old phone (LG G6), and there is **the same behaviour** like on the Xiaomi Mi9

What's the root cause here and how can I fix this?`

Thanks a lot

## Update 01/19

I found out that the page is loading without problems when either

- called while capturing data with "Pcap Remote" android app
  or
- called with TOR browser

What do these facts tell me?

Comment: So basically you can access the page with every device as long as it does not depend on your SIM card?

Comment: Connect your phone to a computer and use USB tethering. Then try to load the web page using the computer and make a Wireshark dump of the page loading. Everything else is just guessing. Anyway: which mobile network provider do you use?

Comment: @0X0nosugar That's correct

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the tip! Just for understanding: Would remote debugging with chrome over USB also help?

Comment: Not really. Remote debugging is good for content debugging in open connections, but in your case the connection is never established. Therefore you need to look at the TLS handshake messages.

Comment: OK I understand, I'll try with USB tethering and come back here with the results, thanks!

Comment: Can you open any other SSL page on that device?

Comment: In Firefox, is there any additional error detail? There is usually some further diagnostic on the error screen. Can you screenshot that message?

Comment: @RodrigoM Yes, every other SSL page is working fine

Comment: Any detailed error message?

Comment: @RodrigoM Unfortunatelly not, the only message is [this](https://static.sager.io/firefox.jpg)

Comment: I'm going  nuts with this... I tried to capture the traffic with an android app called "PCAP Remote" to save it to a pcap file, and while recording the traffic everything works fine... So I can't capture the errors :-(